# How to get the channel name when integrating with Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have created a Microsoft Teams bot that can create/update conversations and receives all kinds of events to an endpoint (channel created, channel renamed, ...).

I'm interested in channel names.

I can see the channel name in the `channelCreated` and `channelRenamed` event. But what about channels that are created before my bot joines the team? How can I get those channel names using the Bot Service/Framework API?

I understand that I could get the channel name from the Graph API. But to get access to the Graph API as a bot, I have to perform the [admin consent dance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795800/1897897) which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.teams.teamsinfo?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable):

```
var channels = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamChannelsAsync(turnContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
foreach (var channel in channels)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(channel.Name);
}
```

Comment: I see. Looks like the General channel has no name field. I get a name for all other channels!